# Using the same clock for multiple shift register

Tags: arduino, clock, shift-register

Sorry for the beginner question.  I'm working on a nixie tube clock and I have a bunch of shift registers for each tube.  Do I need to use a different clock for each IC or can I use the same clock for each register?

Comment: Assuming you're using something similar to a 74HC595 shift register, then, yes, you can wire the same clock to all registers... up to a limit.

Comment: I would be using 6 registers and thank you for the reply

Comment: You can wire the 6 clocks together without a problem. You can also wire the latch pin of all of them together.

Comment: But the other quick things is how would I control 10 numbers if there are only 8 output pins?  And thanks!  Didn't even thing about the latch piin.

Comment: I'll make that an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: I'll up-vote that answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: What do you mean by 10 numbers? Maybe you should back up and explain a little better what it is that you want to do.

Comment: Each tube has 0-9 in it which means 10 numbers inside the tube.  If there are 8 pins on the shift register then there isn't a way to get all the numbers (at least to my limited knowledge)

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: After googling and finding out what a Nixie Tube is, I'm not sure I addressed your question properly, but we'll get there. First thing for you to do is to find the datashet for the part you want to use or already have. Do you have a part number? Google it and update your question to show it to us.

Comment: You answered it quite well.  It was just a matter of being nudged in the right direction.  Never have a software guy work on hardware ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad I could help. But if you provide the datasheets, we'll help you further.

Comment: About having software guys doing hardware (me included), I agree, not safe at all. Especially because they will get hooked on it. But that's more common around here.

Comment: I just realized that my tubes come with some SN74141 BCD ICs so I can use one shift register to control two nixie tubes.  That being said, however, while I'd only need 3 shift registers I'd need 6 SN74141 BCD ICs.  I could just multiplex but I'm a beginner so starting with shift registers is a good starter project :)

Comment: Great! Sounds like you're on top of it now. Good luck! If you have any related questions, ask here (as a separate question). Also helpful will be a schematic diagram of the connections you plan to use. But that's for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using something similar to a 74HC595 shift register, then, yes, you can wire the same clock to all registers.

There's a limit, but it is far more than the 6 shift registers you want to use, so you can safely wire the 6 clocks together without a problem.

You can also wire the latch pin of all of them together.

If the device you need to control has 10 inputs, then you must string more shift registers together and allocate the first register to the first 8 inputs, and the remaining 2 to the second and so on.

So, calculate how many inputs you'll have in total, and then string together the corresponding number of shift registers.

Does that make sense to you?

Comment: That makes sense.  It would make more sense to use a 16 bit register then.

Comment: Well, I'd use whatever is easier for you. I have plenty of 595's in my bins and I'm really familiar with them so I'd use them. Since you can string them together, then it doesn't really matter if you have 8 or 16 bit registers. Unless you have board design constraints or something like that.

Comment: @evan.stoddard Note that if you are building a clock, all of your digits are not 0 through 9, so you will not need 60 output pins for a 6 digit clock. You will find that you need fewer 8-bit shift registers than the 6 you anticipated. I'll leave the actual count to you.

Comment: @Tut Thank you.  Didn't even think about that... the only issue I have with that is cathode poisoning.  I don't want to burn out only one or two numbers on the tubes.

Comment: @Ricardo, what is the limit to how many shift registers you could hook up to the clock line, and how would you calculate that? I am working on a project that requires ~100 shift registers, and want to know if I will run up to a limit.

Comment: @Ross I have no idea, but it seems you may have issues with so many registers. You should really do some research and if nothing comes out, ask a separate question. But if you do ask a separate question, make sure you show good evidence of your research and provide enough detail for the users to answer properly. Oh, and don't forget to provide a decent looking schematic (no Fritzing wiring diagrams allowed). That way you'll ensure that your question is well received here.

Comment: @Ross - A quick googling turned up two hits from SE.EE: [Chaining limit for shift registers in large led matrix](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21623/chaining-limit-for-shift-registers-in-large-led-matrix) and [What problems could occur when chaining 40 shift registers?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/40242/29792). If neither one answers your question, ask your own, but don't forget to mention these and explain why they don't answer your question. This will prevent users from closing yours as duplicate.